# Python parser ply does not handle spaces

Tags: python, parsing, lexer, ply

I parse data using [ply](https://github.com/dabeaz/ply). I try to use a space as part of lexemes. Here a simplified example:

```py
from ply.lex import lex
from ply.yacc import yacc

tokens = ('NUM', 'SPACE')

t_NUM = r'\d+'
t_SPACE = r' '

def t_error(t):
    print(f'Illegal character {t.value[0]!r}')
    t.lexer.skip(1)

lexer = lex()

def p_two(p):
    '''
    two : NUM SPACE NUM
    '''
    p[0] = ('two', p[1], p[2], p[3])

def p_error(p):
    if p:
        print(f"Syntax error at '{p.value}'")
    else:
        print("Syntax error at EOF")

parser = yacc()

ast = parser.parse('1 2')
print(ast)
```

When I run, I've got the error:

```
ERROR: Regular expression for rule 't_SPACE' matches empty string
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\demo\simple_space.py", line 19, in <module>
    lexer = lex()
  File "C:\demo\3rdparty\ply\ply\lex.py", line 752, in lex
    raise SyntaxError("Can't build lexer")
SyntaxError: Can't build lexer
```

Is it possible to specify space as part of lexeme?
A few additional possible tokens:

- `t_COMMENT = r' \#.*'` for comment
- `t_DIVIDE = r': +'` for a divider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is explained in the Ply manual section on [Specification of tokens](https://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn6):

> Internally, lex.py uses the re module to do its pattern matching. Patterns are compiled using the `re.VERBOSE` flag which can be used to help readability. However, be aware that unescaped whitespace is ignored and comments are allowed in this mode. If your pattern involves whitespace, make sure you use `\s`. If you need to match the `#` character, use `[#]`.

So a literal space character must be written as `[ ]` or `\` . (`\s`, as suggested in the manual, matches any whitespace, not just a space character.)

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea why it doesn't work

But it seems it works with [sly](https://github.com/dabeaz/sly) created by the same author
(but few years later - so he could have experience after writing `ply`)

```
from sly import Lexer, Parser

class MyLexer(Lexer):
    tokens = { NUM, SPACE }

    NUM = r'\d+'
    SPACE = r' '

    def error(self, t):
        print(f'Illegal character {t.value[0]!r}')
        t.lexer.skip(1)

class MyParser(Parser):
    tokens = MyLexer.tokens

    @_('NUM SPACE NUM')
    def two(self, p):
        return ('two', p.NUM0, p.SPACE, p.NUM1)
        

lexer = MyLexer()
parser = MyParser()

ast = parser.parse(lexer.tokenize('1 2'))
print(ast)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Interesting is text `'t_SPACE' matches empty string` and it suggested to me that `space` may have special meaning so I tested `"\ "` - and it works

```
t_SPACE = r'\ '
```

Comment: It's interesting that Sly does not compile regexes with `re.VERBOSE`. The Sly docs say that it does, but as you observe it doesn't. Obviously, it's an oversight: either the author forgot to change the docs or he forgot to add the flag to the default settings of the lexer. Sly has never really been released, so one can't complain too much.

Comment: Reported as [issue 94](https://github.com/dabeaz/sly/issues/94)

Comment: @rici it is good idea to set issue